# Select option is being selected many times in jquery event if it is disabled

Tags: jquery, html

I am building a contact form, which has the select drop down of Country. First option tag has a value of country but it has the attribute disabled and selected then comes the options of countries from a php list. The problem i am having is when I print the value of country to the console, i get "CountryCountry" and not "Country" ! i need to know why it is selecting the Country 2 times which is affecting the other values which i get for example "CountryChile" if i select Chile. 
I made a google search but none has asked this question, i couldn't find any answers

here is my html

```
<form action="" method="post" class="contact_us_form">
                <div class="contact_us_label">First Name</div>
                <div class="contact_us_input">
                    <input type="text" name="contact_first_name" class="contact_input" id="contact_first_name" />
                </div>

                <div class="contact_us_label">Last Name</div>
                <div class="contact_us_input">
                    <input type="text" name="contact_last_name" class="contact_input" id="contact_last_name" />
                </div>

                <div class="contact_us_label">Email</div>
                <div class="contact_us_input">
                    <input type="text" name="contact_email" class="contact_input" id="contact_email" />
                </div>

                <div class="contact_us_label">Country</div>
                <div class="contact_us_input">
                    <select class="contact_us_country_option country_input">
                        <option value="Country">Country</option>
                        <?php
                            include 'includes/countries_list.php';
                            foreach ( $countries as $country) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $country;?>">
                            <?php echo $country; ?>
                        </option> 
                        <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="contact_us_label">Subject</div>
                <div class="contact_us_label">
                    <textarea rows="6" cols="70" name="contact_subject" class="contact_subject" id="contact_subject" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" name="contact_us_button" value="Send" class="contact_us_button" id="contact_us_button" disabled/>
                <a href="index.php" class="contact_us_cancel_button">Cancel</a>
            </form>
```

and here is my jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#contact_us_button", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var countryInput = $('.country_input').find(":selected").text().trim();
    console.log(countryInput);
});
```

Comment: Try e.stopPropagation() in your click.

Comment: where should i try it you mean ? in place of e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: Next to it maybe. Since i dont know what your entire html looks like.

Comment: @Jason i placed my entire form, but what i am looking for to make is the select option, I am not able to select it as i am supposed to, can you clarify what would e.stopPropagation() do ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jhnLd2oq/ Seems to work fine here. Any chance your jquery script is called twice from another php file? Check your <script> tags.

Comment: it works on other page but not this page, i checked but it's the first time i use this script, it is an empty page with just these couple of lines related to this submit button

Comment: Your problems have to be reproducible. Otherwise, for the most part, all we can do is guess.

Comment: @Jason then what should i do for it to show ?

Comment: I don't know what was the problem but i simply deleted the line and recopied it from here the value of var countryInput and it worked !! I don't get it what was the problem ?!